# Stop users from editing and deleting data on list

Tags: list, permissions

For a new SharePoint application we're constructing, we have a requirement which says a user may enter data in a list, but may not edit or delete the data.

So I thought of creating a list (probably hidden) and setting the permissions so that a normal user doesn't have Contribute rights on it. But that leaves the problem of inserting. For that I thought of creating my own webpart in which the data could be entered, and I could use elevated privileges to insert the data into the list. But then it would be entered as System Account (created by / modified by) and I don't want to happen: I need it to be created as the logged on user.

Is this possible? Or are there better solutions to satisfy this requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way is to [configure your custom permission level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx), in this permission level you should uncheck Edit and Delete permissions check boxes. [See this post for more permission levels details](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx). After this you can assigne this level to any group in the same way as Contribute.

Comment: Great, didn't even know that was possible. Thanks!

Comment: I found to create a custom permission level, you have to do so from the site collection root.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom list write a event receiver for activated event and then in that give permissions for that list, based on the user groups you can assign the permissions for the list.